# How do I import svelte in the cdn to make svelte work?

Tags: svelte

I want to use svelte but i dont want to download the node_modules.
Could I just import it in html and use it quickly?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <div on:click="{onclick}">123</div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/svelte@3.46.4/index.js"></script>
    <script type="module">
      function onclick() {
        console.log("123");
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your question doesn't really make any sense since Svelte components need to be compiled in the first place anyway...

Comment: is there a html-svelte-compiler for svelte so i could use svelte directly in html?

Comment: No, the entire idea of Svelte is to go against this.

Comment: You can find hacks such as this https://codepen.io/netsi1964/pen/gOGywoV where you can load the compiler and do it on the fly, but I'd recommend using svelte repl for prototyping https://svelte.dev/repl/hello-world?version=3.46.4

Answer (score -2):

You cannot do it with Svelte, but you can do it with Lit (web component minimalistic framework, from Google). It makes  native html components, made with almost vanilla js, with props atributes, and reactivity just like React components. But NATIVELY. That means you can use it on ANY javascript framework, or even dont need them.

Take a look at my example working live with source code:
https://codepen.io/Zehn1984/pen/MWzQRMm

```
    <!-- <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Lit.js Web Component with Reactivity and Attributes</title>
</head>

<body> -->

  <my-component backgroundColor="#000" fontColor="#fff"></my-component> <!-- Change attributes to test! -->

  <script type="module">

    import { LitElement, html } from 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lit@2.7.6/+esm';

    class MyComponent extends LitElement {

      static properties = {
        backgroundColor: { type: String },
        fontColor: { type: String },
      };

      constructor() {
        super();
        this.backgroundColor = 'blue';
        this.fontColor = 'red';
        this.btnText = 'Show';
        this.displayState = 'none';
      }

      toggleShowAndHideText() {
        if (this.btnText === 'Show') {
          this.displayState = 'block';
          this.btnText = 'Hide';
          this.backgroundColor = 'gondenrod';
        } else {
          this.displayState = 'none';
          this.btnText = 'Show';
          this.backgroundColor = this.getAttribute('backgroundColor');
        }
      }

      render() {
        return html`
          <style>
            button {
              background: ${this.backgroundColor};
              color: ${this.fontColor};
            }
            #info-box {
              display: ${this.displayState};
            }  
          </style>

          <button @click=${this.toggleShowAndHideText}>${this.btnText}</button>
          <p id="info-box">More infos!</p>
        `;
      }
    }

    customElements.define('my-component', MyComponent);

  </script>
<!-- </body>

</html> -->
```